# IE textarea selectionStart is wrong after setting value containing newline

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selection-api

If I type `a` and then `<enter>` into an IE11 textarea and log `selectionStart`, it's `2` (which is what I would expect). However, if I set the value of the textarea programmatically to `'a\n'` instead, `selectionStart` is `4`.

```
$('textarea').val('a\n');
console.log($('textarea').get(0).selectionStart);
```

Is there anyway to get an accurate cursor position here?

Comment: Wow, this is weird. Works fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in IE the cursor doesn't move unless the textarea has been given focus first.

Try

```
$('textarea').focus().val('a\n');
console.log($('textarea').get(0).selectionStart);
```